# uWebSockets static library installed via vcpkg but dll are still needed for executable on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg, uwebsockets

I have a Visual Studio C++ project that is making use of uWebSockets.  The Visual Studio project file is configured to output a `.dll` that is used during runtime of a host executable.  I need some of uWebSockets' functionality for my `.dll`.  I want the project to link to the static libraries of uWebSockets.  I used `vcpkg` to install it:

`vcpkg install uwebsockets:x64-windows-static`

And sure enough, after vcpkg does its thing, I can navigate to `.vspkg\installed\x64-windows-static\lib` and see the listing of `.lib` files that I assume are ready to be satically linked.

```
uSockets.lib
uv_a.lib
zlib.lib
```

Back in Visual Studio project configuration window, I set the "Additional Library Directories" to include the `.vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static\lib` and set the "Additional Include Directories" to the `\includes` path that `vcpkg` installed.

Everything builds as expected with Visual Studio.  The problem is that the host app will not load the built `.dll` unless the `uSockets.dll` and `zlib1.dll` files are in the same directory as the running executable.  To get those, I had to run `vcpkg install uwebsockets:x64-windows`  When `vcpkg` finished installing that one, there is a `bin` directory that contains the `.dlls`.

To verify that `vcpkg` actually installed true static libs, not "import libraries", I ran the following on the `uSockets.lib` file in `vcpkg`'s`x64-windows-static` dir:

`lib /list uSockets.lib"

And I see this output:

```
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.30.30706.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

CMakeFiles\uSockets.dir\src\bsd.c.obj
CMakeFiles\uSockets.dir\src\context.c.obj
CMakeFiles\uSockets.dir\src\eventing\epoll_kqueue.c.obj
CMakeFiles\uSockets.dir\src\eventing\gcd.c.obj
CMakeFiles\uSockets.dir\src\eventing\libuv.c.obj
CMakeFiles\uSockets.dir\src\loop.c.obj
CMakeFiles\uSockets.dir\src\socket.c.obj
```

That, to me, says "static lib" as opposed to an import lib. When I run the same command for `uSockets.lib` in the `x64-windows` install directory, I get the following:

```
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.30.30706.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

uSockets.dll
uSockets.dll
uSockets.dll
uSockets.dll
...
uSockets.dll
uSockets.dll
uSockets.dll
uSockets.dll
```

That looks like an import lib.

So my question is why are the uSockets.dll and libz1.dll needed at the executable's runtime if they are truly static libraries?  When I use `vcpkg install uwebsockets:x64-windows-static` why would I still need to place the `.dll`'s for those libs next to the executable.  I thought the point of static libraries was so that you don't need to ship the `.dll`s with the application.